# Django self.assertEqual comparing 2 new unsaved objects

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have a `CustomerProfile` model

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

and when I run the `assertEqual` on 2 unsaved objects, it raises `AssertionError`

```
self.assertEqual(
    CustomerProfile(billing_profile=default_profile), 
    CustomerProfile(billing_profile=default_profile)
)
```

Gives the following error:

`AssertionError: <CustomerProfile:  Full Charge None> != <CustomerProfile:  Full Charge None>`

I don't understand why because the instance id would not have been populated since it's unsaved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special support in `assertEqual` for comparing Django models.
Unless the models have been saved (i.e. have a primary key) then [they are comparing by identity](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2/django/db/models/base.py#L531) (CPython: [memory location](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)), which will always be different for two separate unsaved model instances, even if every field is the same.

To compare unsaved model instances based on content, you would need to manually check that the data in all the relevant fields are equal. Third-party `testfixtures` has a helper for this: see [`django_compare`](https://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html).

Comment: but why comparing 2 different lists works? `self.assertEqual(['1'], ['1])` I have checked both have different IDs.

Comment: Because lists don't compare by identity.  They implement an `__eq__` method to compare by value.

Comment: I see, thanks, what would you recommend to test 2 different unsaved model objects?

Comment: Check that all the relevant data in all their fields are equal.

Comment: This answer isn't true at all. There is a fairly complex [`__eq__` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L524) for Django models, which checks by PK but falls back to identity if the models are not saved, which is what is happening here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks - for unsaved models the pk is None, so this is still an identity comparison. But I'll edit to not gloss over the details.